# Laravel - Pluck data of multiple columns from a single row and use for drop-down

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a hard time populating a drop-down that contains data from different columns. I am able to do it per row, but not per column from a single row.

**tbl_salary_matrix**

```
id | position_id | year_experience | salary_minimum | salary_median | salary_maximum

1    1             below 3           $1,000           $1,500          $2,000
```

I want the three salary column to be populated to a drop-down. This is the current code I'm using to create a dynamic drop-down getting the data from each row. The code below is being used from another form, I want to create a new code for the salary matrix form.

**Controller**

```
  public function getSectionList(Request $request) {
    $getSection = SectionModel::where("department_id", $request->department_id)->pluck('section_name', 'id');
    return response()->json($getSection);
  }
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('get-section-list-employee','EmployeeController@getSectionList');
```

**Blade.php**

```
                 <div class="form-group col-md-12 row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Department') }}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Please Select Department</option>
                            @foreach ($getDepartment as $id => $department)
                            <option value="{{$id}}">{{ $department }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-12 row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Section') }}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="section" name="section" class="form-control">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#department').change(function(){
var departmentID = $(this).val();    
    if(departmentID) {
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"{{url('get-section-list-employee')}}?department_id="+departmentID,
    success:function(res){               
        if(res) {
        $("#section").empty();
        $("#section").append('<option>Please Select Section</option>');
        $.each(res,function(key, value){
            $("#section").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
        });
      } else {
        $("#section").empty();
      }
    }
  });
} else {
    $("#section").empty();
   }      
    });
</script>
```

How do I convert this code in order to have a drop-down that gets data from all three columns (salary_minimum, salary_median, salary_maximum) that are in a single row?

Thank you very much and have a great day ahead!

**EDIT: SOLVED (courtesy of [Kévin Bibollet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5878071/k%C3%A9vin-bibollet))**

```
 $salaries = SalaryMatrixModel::where(...)->first(); 
return response()->json([$salaries['salary_minimum'], $salaries['salary_median'], $salaries['salary_maximum']]);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: is section related to department? you'd need to be able to relate them together and formulate a method for the model, from there just glue them together with the controller and call it in your ajax

Comment: What did you try? I don't see something relative about salaries but your table in the code you're showing us.

Comment: Hi @Kevin! Yup Section is related to department. The code that I posted was for getting a loop for each row, it is an example of what I use. But I don't know how will I use it in getting per column. I'll be using the salary matrix for a different form.



Hi @KévinBibollet! The table salary matrix is for another form, I just showcased a code that I use in retrieving data for each row, but I don't know how can I retrieve data from each column (for salary matrix)

Comment: You could create (then return) an array (or a collection) containing your columns : `$salaries = SalaryMatrixModel::where(...)->first(); return response()->json([$salaries['salary_minimum'], $salaries['salary_median'], $salaries['salary_maximum']]);`. Probably needs to be adapted, but I think that could be the start of what you want to achieve!

Comment: @KévinBibollet Wow it works! Thank you very much! You are a life savior. I didn't know you could do this in a response()->json. Editing post so I could share the answer to everyone.

Comment: No problem! Of course you can do that, in Laravel, the data you get from a model are stored in a collection, which are - more or less - arrays. And since `json()` is waiting for an array, you can give it an already stored array (like in `getSectionList`) or directly build your array like I did. ;)